# How to stop the song from playing in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs6

I am trying to stop the song from playing when user clicks on a button, this is my code :

```
var mySound:MainSound = new MainSound();
var cmyChannel :SoundChannel;

animation_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

function playSound(event:Event) {
mySound.play();
}

animation_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
function stopSound(event:Event) {
mySound.stop();
}


animation_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,    fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

when i click on the animation_play object it works perfectly fine, it does as how it should be by playing the sound and starting the animation from the specified frame. however if i click on animation_stop object i get an error

```
TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
```

Anyone know how to go about fixing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `mySound.play()` to the `cmyChannel` object. Then call `stop` on `cmyChannel`. Here is the code:

```
var mySound:MainSound = new MainSound();
var cmyChannel :SoundChannel;

animation_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);

function playSound(event:Event) {
cmyChannel  = mySound.play();
}

animation_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);
function stopSound(event:Event) {
cmyChannel.stop();
}


animation_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,    fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop your sound, you have to use a `SoundChannel` object like this, for example :

```
function playSound(event:Event): void 
{
    cmyChannel = mySound.play();
}
```

and

```
function stopSound(event:Event): void  
{
    cmyChannel.stop();
}
```

Hope that can help.